# Page displaying properly after second load in ie9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I am using jquery BlocksIt plugin in my application, below is part my code

```
$(window).load( function() {
$('#container-pinterest').BlocksIt({
  numOfCol: 3,
  offsetX: 4,
  offsetY: 5,
  adjustWidth: true,
  blockElement: 'div'
});
  var currentWidth = 1100;
      var winWidth = $(window).width();
var conWidth;
if(winWidth < 660) {
  conWidth = 440;
  col = 1;
} else if(winWidth < 880) {
  conWidth = 660;
  col = 2;
} else if(winWidth < 1100) {
  conWidth = 880;
  col = 3;
} else {
  conWidth = 1100;
  col = 3;
}
if(conWidth != currentWidth) {
  currentWidth = conWidth;
  $('#container-pinterest').width(conWidth);
  $('#container-pinterest').BlocksIt({
    numOfCol: col,
    offsetX: 4,
    offsetY: 12
  });
}
});
```

Actually I am loading some images here. In Chrome, Firefox, IE10 and IE11 it's working properly but in IE9 the images are loading slowly and BlocksIt functionality is not working properly.

When I refresh the page again it is working fine. But first time problem

Any help

Answer (score 0):

Try to add special `onLoad` listener to your images

```
$("img").one("load", function () {
    /* your code here*/
    $(#container-pinterest).BlocksIt({
        numOfCol: 3,
        offsetX: 4,
        offsetY: 5,
        adjustWidth: true,
        blockElement: 'div'
    });
    /* your code here*/
}).each(function () {
    if (this.complete) $(this).load(); // if image is cached call onload manualy
});
```

Since window is loaded a bit earlier then image that is why it cause your problem.